# Plsql Error handling does line number comes with user error code

Tags: oracle, plsql

hi guys I wrote a code on plsql in error handling I used the
raise _application_error function in toad tool I got the error as output but I also got a sys error and line no of error it is general output or I there any mistake in the code..

error output

```
[72000][20001] ORA-20001: Loop Done -user output
ORA-06512: at line 14 - sys error
Position: 0 - sys error
```

is line no common

if any solution pls help..

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help if you posted piece of code that illustrates what you did and how Oracle responded (or, at least, screenshot).

This is how error stack *usually* looks like:

```
SQL> begin
  2    raise_application_error(-20001, 'My error message');
  3  end;
  4  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: My error message
ORA-06512: at line 2


SQL>
```

So - yes, **line number** is displayed (if that answers your question).